# Google Places Added place not showing

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API to add a place under my api key. I am able to successfully create the place and view details for it, but it doesn't show it on the map on my iPhone app also using the same key. Has anyone else come across this issue

I send the request to, which works:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=MYKEY`

I made sure it created the place by sending the following request with the id of the place that I just created:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=idofplace`

This returns the correct place. If I then go to my iPhone app which gets results using the same API Key and a nearby search, the item doesn't appear on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the place showed in the json search response? Please make sure you are not using the iOS key. `The Places API does not work with an Android or iOS API key.` You can try using the nearby search, sample request: 
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters

Need to make sure the place is within the radius of your supplied location, **however if your request radius is too large, your result will get into the `next_page_token`**

I was able to POST a new place and GET it from nearby search with following requests:

**POST:** `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=YOUR_KEY`

```
{ "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Stackoverflow!",
  "phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
  "address": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "website": "http://www.google.com.au/",
  "language": "en-AU"
}
```

**GET:** `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&key=YOUR_KEY&radius=50`

Then search the name `Stackoverflow` in the json response. (You can past the GET request link directly in your browser too)

According to the Places API documentation, `new places will be available immediately in place nearby searches initiated by your application.` However, a newly-added place will not appear in place text search or radar search results, or to other applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process.

***Places that have been added by your application can also be deleted, until they have been moderated. Once moderated and added into the full place search results, a place can no longer be deleted. Places that are not accepted by the moderation process will continue to be visible to the application that submitted them.***
For more information, please refer to the [Place Action documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#place).

Comment: My nearby search does return results, but doesn't include the one that I added. I have also verified that the api keys are the same. Regarding the next page, my nearby search radius is very large, but this hasn't caused me any other problems. I have figured out exactly where the location I added should be and there are many results surrounding it, just not the one I added.

Comment: Also, if this is related to next_page_token, is there any way to bump my added place up to the first page. I am trying to make the result show on the map on a production iOS app. Would be great if I didn't have to update the app to fix this.

Comment: If you want to bump up your result, you can try to put the optional parameters, keyword, name or types. I am able to find the place i added, what lat/lng and radius you used for testing?

Comment: I am using a radius of 7000 and at lat/lng of 34.026634,-118.472503. The lng/lat of my place is 34.031190,-118.461563

Comment: seems the newly added place is usually in a very last few pages, there is no API request to sort the output. I was able to find the place with `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.026634,-118.472503&key=YOUR_KEY&radius=7000&name=YOUR_NAME` I guess you need to add some optional parameters to filter the results.

Comment: I added the name to the request and it is still not showing. Any other possible solutions?

Comment: I am also filtering by the types school and university. Will this make any difference?

Comment: Disregard my last comment, it does show if I add the name parameter. The problem is that I am trying to find all the places of a specific type in the area, so putting in a specific name would cause problems.

Comment: You tried restrict the result by putting the `types` parameter in your GET request? I guess even you do, you will still get lots of results. I dont see there is a way to sort the results in the Places API yet. It also seems the newly added places will be in the last page of the results.

Comment: I have successfully found a work around, but I am now having problems deleting a few of the extra places created while trying to get this to work. I keep getting request denied while sending the request. I have verified that the key I am using is the same as the one used to post. I would really appreciate it if you could help. You can see the whole question here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746010/cannot-delete-place-using-places-api`